# Gulp pump error: Error: pump requires two streams per minimum

Tags: gulp

I have a simple delete task created in Gulp. It deletes the dist folder

```
// DELETE TASK
var DIST_PATH = 'public/dist';
gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
  pump([del.sync([DIST_PATH])], cb);
});
```

But I am getting this error message: Error: pump requires two streams per minimum

What is happening and any ideas how to solve this?
Thx
Lino

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** You only provide 1 stream in the array that is the first parameter of pump while 2 is the minimum. Consider doing

```
// DELETE TASK
var DIST_PATH = 'public/dist';
gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
  del.sync([DIST_PATH])
  .on('error', function(error) { console.error('ERROR: '+ error.toString() } )
});
```

**Long answer:**
I was trying to uglify my concatenated es6 script and that failed leaving me with these none-useful stack-trace. It was my first go on Gulp so lots of roadblocks (e.g. javascript6 is not supported  by uglify out-of-the-box).
Everybody says: 'use pump'. So I start using pump and then got the same error as you did. It seems like a totally incomprehensible error message but is giving you the clue you need.

You need to give at least 2 streams in the first parameter (the array) of pump. For a gulp newbie: streams mean the string of (sub-)tasks you want gulp to perform. So the following code gave me the the same error as yours because I only provide pump with one stream.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var uglifyes = require('uglify-es'); //for es6 to work
var composer = require('gulp-uglify/composer');//for es6 to work
var uglify = composer(uglifyes, console);//for es6 to work
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var pump = require('pump');

gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
  pump([
      gulp.src(['js/file0.js','js/file1.js')
      .pipe(concat('all.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.js' }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
    ],
    callback);
});
```

But then looked closer at the examples and saw that you have to cut up the stream in its separate sub-tasks. I rewrote the gulp task to

```
gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
  pump([
      gulp.src(['js/file0.js','js/file1.js']),
      concat('all.js'),
      gulp.dest('build'),
      uglify(),
      rename({ extname: '.min.js' }),
      gulp.dest('build')
    ],
    callback);
});
```

Notice that all .pipe() calls have been removed and all sub-tasks (i.e. the streams) have been separated by coma's thereby adding not 1 but at least 2 streams in the array parameter of pump.

My two cents

[gulp-uglify](/questions/tagged/gulp-uglify)